# What's the shortcut to hide the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In order to open the integrated terminal, there is a shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>. Is there a shortcut to hide the terminal?

Comment: try the same key `ctrl` + `

Comment: Answer `Ctrl/Cmd+j` by HaaLeo also works when opening terminal with: `Shift+enter`.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Using VS Code 1.41.1 on windows, <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> toggles the panel view.

You can look up the default keybinding for your OS by opening the *Keyboard Shortcuts* view and searching for the `workbench.action.togglePanel` command. In case it is not asigned yet to a default shortcut or you prefer another one, you can adjust the keybinding in this view as well.

Comment: cmd + J on mac works

Comment: I should note that this answer works if you terminal panel is on the bottom, if you have it as a side panel like me, you should set a hotkey for `view: Toggle Side Panel`.

Comment: CTRL + J on Ubuntu works also.

Comment: I can't believe I had to google this.... why isn't there an icon for this, I hate having that window there when not in use

Comment: @Gerry I had to do the same, they have a maximize button but not minimize. UX take notes on what NOT to do.

Comment: @Gerry - The UI for this is right click... you can right click on the titlebar of the panel.  You will see options to "Hide Panel" and also move it to the side/bottom

Answer (score 29):

You can use same <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to toggle appearance of terminal. If you want to keep both open and jump around, use below

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>  to jump in terminal

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>  to jump back in editor

Answer (score 17):

For OS X, the command is to show/hide the terminal is `COMMAND + J`

Answer (score 4):

In **keybindings.json**, copy following JSON lines:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+'",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal",
    "when": "!terminalFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+'",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
```

you can change `ctrl+'` by what shortcut you like.

Comment: Another useful command is @command:workbench.action.toggleAuxiliaryBar. One can also use it to set the keybindings when the terminal is at the right-side panel.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Command `⌘` + `J` Hide Panel

###### Environment

```
Visual Studio Code Version: 1.63.2 
macOS Monterey Version 12.1 x86_64
```

Answer (score -2):

For MacOS users the keyboard shortcut is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd>

(VS Code v.1.47.3)

Comment: This is incorrect. I tried and this doesn't work.